# Pass AJAX Variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

Hi so my over all aim is to click a table get its ID and then use its ID to load another table. So far I am able to get the ID, but when I try to load the second table I get the error

> "Undefined index: Projec_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\abac\ajaxupdate.php on
>   line 6 "

Here's my Code

AJAX Script(Console prints the rowID so it is getting, the variable I think something is going wrong when trying to pass it?)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var log = $("#log");

    $(".getRow").click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked a row...");
    rowID = $(this).find("td.idCell").text();

    //Print the row ID in the log cell to make sure we got the right one.
    log.text("You 1clicked row "+rowID);
    console.log("You cl2icked row "+rowID);

    //Send the row ID to ajaxupdate.php

     $.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", { what: "updateRow", Projec_ID: rowID})
    .done( function(data) {
    var results = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(rowID );
    })
    .fail( function() {
    console.log("AJAX POST failed.");
    });
    });

    });
</script>
```

PHP File (ajaxupdate.php) I think there is something wrong here im guessing

```
<?php 

     if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) ||  (isset($_POST['Projec_ID'])) )
     {     
        $Projec_ID =($_POST['Projec_ID']);
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('CV_ID', 'Classifier', 'Value', 'TP_ID')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('sessionta'))
          //also is the like  part right?
    ->where($db->quoteName('TP_ID') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($_POST['Projec_ID']));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    //echo $Classifier;
     }
?>
```

Comment: Is your form set to use POST or GET? <form method="GET"> or <form method="POST">? Looks like it probably is POST but just checking

Comment: did you try using,$Projec_ID =$_POST['Projec_ID'];

Comment: Check your AJAX request headers and make sure Projec_ID is being passed to the Server. I use Google Development Tools to check this. Also why do you assign `$Projec_ID = $_POST['Projec_ID']`, but then never use it.

Comment: After looking at your JQuery I think changing `rowID = $(this).find("td.idCell").text();` to  `var rowID = $(this).find("td.idCell").text();` this is because `rowId` is not in the scope of the `$.post()` JQuery function call. And may solve your problem.

Comment: @Rottingham My form is set to post? Should it be set to get?

Comment: No, you want POST in this case

Comment: @Richard Christensen I might have written wrongly I thought i was using in the where statement? Okay ill try with your statement now

Comment: @Richard Christensen Unfortunately still the same 

Notice: Undefined index: Projec_ID in

Comment: @user3425742 did you check the headers of the AJAX request to see what data is being passed to the Server?

Comment: @Richard ChristensenNew to AJAX how do i CHeck this?

Comment: You can check this via the `<?php` in my answer - furthermore, I edited it with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['submit']` will be false unless you set it: 
`[...] { "what": "updateRow", "Projec_ID": rowID, "submit" : "true"}`

Which is why you get the error message "Undefined Index" -!

Furthermore, you can always:

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>"; 
die("The data above was sent via POST");
```

to troubleshoot these sorts of things..

Comment: Quotes are nore required for JSON data keys.

Copied from: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

`$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`

Comment: Then throw in that PHP block. `$_POST['submit']` is not set anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand?

Comment: That PHP block above will help you troubleshoot your POST - as well as read what data is being passed to the script -- simple block of debugging --- your problem, however, is that `$_POST['submit']` never gets set- -- thus, your code: `if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) [...]` will return false -- albeit, now I see you've got `||` in there and not `&&` ....

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you are using an || operator and not an && operator.

```
if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) ||  (isset($_POST['Projec_ID'])) )
```

What this means if at some point you pass $_POST['submit'] and not $_POST['Projec_ID'] it will still run this code. giving you the

```
"Undefined index: Projec_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\abac\ajaxupdate.php on line 6 "
```

Try changing your code to:

```
if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) &&  (isset($_POST['Projec_ID'])) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ive stopped getting the the "Undefined index: Projec_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\abac\ajaxupdate.php on line 6 "

But now nothing is loading, even when I try to use a preloaded value like ("12") ? Also im I using the Where Statement Correctly

->where($db->quoteName('TP_ID') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('".$_POST['Projec_ID']."'));

Comment: This is because it is bypassing the code altogether so the problem is still there, this solution just eliminated the error. What you need to do is `var_dump( $_POST );` or `print_r( $_POST );` what this will do is show you exactly what variables are present in your $_POST variable array. Then from there you can better debug your solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think Project_ID isn't going as a string..

Try this code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var log = $("#log");

    $(".getRow").click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked a row...");
    rowID = $(this).find("td.idCell").text();

    //Print the row ID in the log cell to make sure we got the right one.
    log.text("You 1clicked row "+rowID);
    console.log("You cl2icked row "+rowID);

    //Send the row ID to ajaxupdate.php

     $.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", { what: "updateRow", "Projec_ID": rowID})
    .done( function(data) {
    var results = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(rowID );
    })
    .fail( function() {
    console.log("AJAX POST failed.");
    });
    });

    });
</script>
```

i just enclosed Projec_ID with with " .